# Is there any way to retrieve data from dictionary with a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say there is a dictionary and a tuple, I want use the tuple as keys to retrieve values from the dictionary, and then put the result into another tuple.

For example, the dictionary and the tuple are below

`dic = {"b": "bad", "a": "alpha", "c": "change"}`

`tup = ("a", "b", "c")`,

and what I want is another tuple: `("alpha", "bad", "change")`, is there any approach to do that?

And to be more specific, what I try to implement is to get the `dic.values()` result in a sequence that I desire. I am aware of the `collections.OrderedDict()` function, but the function is not available in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
result = [dic[i] for i in tup]

print tuple(result)
("alpha", "bad", "change")
```

Comment: @sshanshank Of course! I tried to accept it at my first sight, but you know about the 12-minutes limit, right? Thanks for you answer again

Comment: @fish748 Note that you don't need to create an intermediate `list` (see my answer). I mention this because you asked for a `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
>>> value_tuple = tuple(dic[k] for k in tup)
>>> print value_tuple
('alpha', 'bad', 'change')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print tuple(map(dic.get, tup))
# ('alpha', 'bad', 'change')
```

This code means that, for every value in `tup`, get the corresponding value from `dic`.